# Отображение определенных объектов на карте OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, ol3

На странице есть карта и 3 checkbox`а, на карте есть слой с двумя точками.

Необходимо по выбору определенного чекбоксу отображать/скрывать одноименную точку. Получилось скрывать только весь слой, но как скрыть один объект?

```js
$('#allTeam').change(function() {
  if (!$(this).is(":checked"))
    $(".checkbox").prop("checked", false);
  else
    $(".checkbox").prop("checked", true);
});

var point_one = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.539502, 55.769378])),
  name: "point1"
});

var point_two = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([38.539502, 55.669358])),
  name: "point2"
});

var pointSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [point_one, point_two]
});

var pointLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: pointSource
});

var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.739502, 55.659368]),
    zoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 16,
    minZoom: 2
  })
});
map.addLayer(pointLayer);

var checkbox = document.getElementById('allTeam');

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var checked = this.checked;
  if (checked !== pointLayer.getVisible()) {
    pointLayer.setVisible(checked);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='point1' checked/>
    <label for='point1'>point1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='point2' checked/>
    <label for='point2'>point2</label>
  </li>
  <hr>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='allTeam' checked/>
    <label for='allTeam'>Отобразить все</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл я про свой вопрос уже, но вот вспомнил, решил проблему вот таким способом:

```
var clickItem = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox'); // получаем все чекбоксы
for (var i = 0; i < clickItem.length; i++) {  // идем по этим чекбоксам
    clickItem[i].addEventListener("change", function() { 
        var number = this.id;
        var checked = this.checked;
        var routeS = routeSource.getFeatures(); // берем фьючи со слоя

        for (var j = 0; j < routeS.length; j++) {  // проходимся по всем фьючам
            if (routeS[j].get('number') === number) { // если номер фьючи равен номеру чекбокса
                if (!checked) {
                    var styleR = [new ol.style.Style({stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: [0,0,0,0]})})]; // прозрачность на 0 (возможно можно сделать какой нибудь visible, но я не нашел)
                }
                routeS[j].setStyle(styleR); // применяем стиль
                break;
            };
        };

    });
}
```